# Shared variable indexing error in theano

Tags: indexing, gpu, theano

There's problem on shared variable indexing.

The shape of train_set_x is (n, 3, 50176) and n is larger than index

I can get value from shared variable train_set_x with following code

```
train_set_x.get_value(borrow=True)[index]
```

`array([[ 143.,  142.,  142., ...,  141.,  141.,  145.],
       [ 114.,  113.,  113., ...,  141.,  141.,  145.],
       [ 108.,  107.,  107., ...,  139.,  139.,  143.]], dtype=float32)`

but I can't get value with following code

```
check = theano.function([index], x, givens = {x : train_set_x[index]})
check(index)
```

It shows an error message

```
*** IndexError: index out of bounds
Apply node that caused the error: GpuSubtensor{int64}(<CudaNdarrayType(float32, 3D)>, ScalarFromTensor.0)
Toposort index: 1
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, 3D), Scalar(int64)]
Inputs shapes: [(1039, 3, 50176), ()]
Inputs strides: [(150528, 50176, 1), ()]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 1039]
Outputs clients: [[HostFromGpu(GpuSubtensor{int64}.0)]]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

What is the difference between them? and What would be the way to use the the value in train_set_x with theano.function?

Comment: What is 'x' ? It should be ftensor3() with dtype=float32.

Comment: 'x' is theano.tensor.tensor3 variable. I tried with ftensor3 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `Inputs values: ['not shown', 1039]` shows value passed as index argument (it is 1039) and the `Inputs shapes: [(1039, 3, 50176), ()]` line shows that your `n` is 1039.

So it looks like you are really out of bounds as theano says.
The following sample works for me:

```
train_set_x = theano.shared(np.random.rand(10, 3, 3))
x = theano.tensor.matrix()
index = theano.tensor.iscalar()
check = theano.function([index], x, givens = {x : train_set_x[index]}
check(3)
```

While `check(10)` displays very similar error:

```
IndexError: index out of bounds
Apply node that caused the error: Subtensor{int32}(<TensorType(float64, 3D)>, ScalarFromTensor.0)
Toposort index: 1
Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, 3D), Scalar(int32)]
Inputs shapes: [(10, 3, 3), ()]
Inputs strides: [(72, 24, 8), ()]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 10]
Outputs clients: [[DeepCopyOp(Subtensor{int32}.0)]]

HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node
```

Comment: Can you please explain why check(10) throws error ? Isn't the number of samples 10 in given example ?

Comment: @Shyamkkhadka, Yes it 10 is the number of samples but index is zero based so the last sample has index 9.